# Application terminates before all callbacks finishes

Tags: java, xml-parsing, callback

I am using this API to parse wikipedia dump available at

```
http://code.google.com/p/wikixmlj/
```

I am using my API as like this

```
Class wiki
{
  public void parseWiki()
  {

      PageCallbackHandler handler = new WikiPageCallbackHandler()
      WikiXMLSAXParser.parseWikipediaDump(filepath, handler )
   }

    }

Class WikiPageCallbackHandler implements PageCallbackHandler 
{
    //Override
    //This is the callback
   void process(WikiPage page)
   {
        String Text = page.GetText();
        //Write this text into a file
        .....
   }
}
```

The issue is before all callbacks are done and I finish writing it into a file, the application is terminating and I am not getting all callbacks.
I want to know why this is happening and is there any way to hold my main thread, so that I get all my callbacks. Also, How would I know if I have got all my callbacks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try using 'Semaphore' at [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).
Here's an example use of `Semaphore`:

```
class wiki
{
    public void parseWiki(){
        // initialize Semaphore object
        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1); 
        //pass it to callback handler so it can release semaphore latter
        PageCallbackHandler handler = new WikiPageCallbackHandler(semaphore);
        //This is the async operation, right?
        WikiXMLSAXParser.parseWikipediaDump(filepath, handler );
        //wait until a permit is available (when semaphore.release() is called)
        semaphore.acquire(); //this throw InterruptedException, please handle it else where
    }
}

class WikiPageCallbackHandler implements PageCallbackHandler 
{
    private Semaphore semaphore;
    public WikiPageCallbackHandler(Semaphore semaphore){
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
    }
    //Override
    //This is the callback
    void process(WikiPage page)
    {
        try{
            String Text = page.GetText();
            //Write this text into a file
            .....
        }finally{
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }
}
```